# The response received in AJAX call is shown in another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, ajax

I have ajax request call which sends an ID to the server, then the server sends a JSON response. I want to update the innerHTML of the pre tag using the value in that JSON Response.

**Form HTML**

```
<form id="AssociateForm" class="form form-inline" style="float:right" action="{% url 'Project:MyView' TR.id %}" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="JIRA_ID" style="width:150px" placeholder="ID" class="form-control has-success" id="{{TR.id}}">
        <button name="button" type="submit" id='Submit_{{TR.id}}' class="btn btn-primary">Associate</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
    $("#AssociateForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        var local_id = $('input[name=J_ID]').attr('id'); 

        var formData = {
            'J_ID' : $('input[name=J_ID]').val()
        };
        console.log(formData)

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (datas) {
                var data = JSON.parse(datas);
                if(datas.status){
                    alert(datas);
                   //$('#Failure_'+local_id).innerHTML = data.category + ' issue: '+data.j_id +' ('+data.j_status+')'
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                alert("In error")
            }
        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data)
        });
    });
</script>
```

for some reason, the above code is not printing the console log as well.

But,

When the response comes, the success section is not triggered. Instead, the complete JSON string is printed on a different page.

**JSON Response**

`{"category": "known", "j_id": "AU298", "j_status": "Confirmed"}`

below is from View-Page-source

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
     <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">

        {"category": "known", "j_id": "AU298", "j_status": "Confirmed"}

     </pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `if(datas.status){` but you probably want `if (data.status) {`. Also it looks like your Django backend is wrapping the JSON response in HTML, which is probably not what you want. Trying to parse that using `JSON.parse()` should result in an error message. Anyway, please add the <form> html to the question so we can take a look. Chances are the form is submitted the regular way and your ajax code never runs in the first place.

Comment: Added the form HTML

Comment: I changed it to `$("#AssociateForm").on('submit', function(e)` which seems to work.

Comment: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Got this error when I removed the {% csrf_token %}.

So you were right, AJAX was not being triggered at first place.

Comment: ...right, that's a very different problem unrelated to this question. Try googling the error.

Comment: Changed to this `$("#AssociateForm").on('submit', function(e)` Still the problem remains.

Comment: As far as I can tell, submitting the form never triggers the event handler, so the submission event is never prevented and the browser simply sends the form and displays the result in a new tab, as per the `<form>` tag. Can you tell us which versions of jQuery and Bootstrap you're using?

Comment: `{% load bootstrap3 %}`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I need the rendered tags from the browser's source view, not Django template code. Guessing at the bootstrap 3 version and code I'm getting an error about bootstrap requiring jQuery but the ajax code is called: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1ugzdno9/

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because you are submitting a form, and after submitting it will open a new tab, as Form is submitted.
To resolve this, you can probably use the below code:

```
<form action="..." method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" id="btn-form-submit"/>
</form>
<script>
 $('#btn-submit').click( function(){ $('#btn-form-submit').click(); } );
</script>
```

Comment: $('#btn-submit'), where is this coming from?

Comment: in your case it would be `Submit_{{TR.id}}` if of button

Comment: `Submit_{{TR.id}}` is dynamic, will keep changing. So how can I have a common script which handles this?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (datas) {
            if (datas.status) {
                alert(datas);
                $('pre#<ID>').html(datas.category + ' issue: ' + datas.j_id + ' (' + datas.j_status + ')');
            }
        }
```

Comment: No need parse json `var data = JSON.parse(datas);`. it'll be json already because you have given dataType json.

Comment: True, but OP's issue is that the event handling code didn't interrupt the form submission.

Comment: There is a django view which does as below:

`
response['category'] = TR.category
response['j_id'] = JI.j_id
response['j_status'] = JI.status

return JsonResponse(response)
`

Comment: `When the response comes, the success section is not triggered. Instead, the complete JSON string is printed on a different page.` For this, you can use `return false` at last in the submit function.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I removed the form completely.

**Code in-place of Form**

```
 <div class="form-group AssociateForm" style="float:right">
    <input type="text" name="J_ID" style="width:150px;float:left" class="form-control has-success">
    <button name="button" type="submit" id="{{TR.id}}" class="Associater btn btn-primary">Associate</button>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
      $('.Associater').on('click', function () {
        var local_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var j_id = $(this).closest("div.AssociateForm").find('input[name=J_ID]').val();

        if (j_id === "") {
            alert("JID cannot be empty")
            return false
        }
        var url = "{% url 'Project:View' 0 %}".replace('0', local_id);

        var formData = {
            'J_ID' : j_id,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        };        
        console.log(local_id);
        console.log(j_id);
        console.log(url);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status) {
                    ele = 'Failure_'+local_id;
                    document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = data.category + ' issue: '+data.j_id +' ('+data.j_status+')';
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert("For some reason im here");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```